# PHP - alternate option for session start in php

Tags: php

I am writing my php application using `session start`. It's working good in offline mode, But when I run it online, it is no longer working good.

Will anyone tell me is any other option for `session start();`

Comment: How its working offline? what do you mean by offline and online can you explain please?

Comment: What you mean by *not working good* ? Be more specific. Also add your post your code to get helped ?

Comment: what kind error, warning, or problem you are facing

Comment: maybe the missing underscore(_) in session_start();

Comment: @crack  : my code is not fetching my function.php file (function of my code) I asked someone he told me use another option instead of session start(); its not working on server. and Its not fetching my other code it is missing all my design images.

Comment: @Jm Verastingue : no I have written session start(); as session_start(); in my code.

Comment: @Rikesh and Roopedra  : when I am checking it on my localhost it is showing all images and div and code is working proper. but when I upload it on server it is not showing my images and my code is not working good.

Comment: session_start() sets only a cookie. why should your images which are linked in html affected? check with firebug or browsers developertools what is the error, please.

Answer (score 1):

Put `ob_start()` at the begining of the code and at the end of the code `ob_flush()` because your headers are already sent and session_start will throw an error.

example :

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

// any code here

ob_flush();

?>
```

Comment: I have to remove session_start from my code or not before putting ob_start()

Comment: Don't remove session_start just put ob_start() at the beginning and ob_flush() at the end of the code.

Comment: or can you please post your error message or the link to the site where that error throw

Comment: I am writting code for messaging system. it is not showing any error just missing all images and I used iframe in my code it is showing code instead of my design or username. and also not fetching my header.php, function.php , connect.php file.

Comment: "it is showing code instead of my design or username" are you sure Apache server is up ? can you post link to your web site ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ob_start()` at the begining of the code and `ob_flush` at the end of your code..

For eg ....

```
<?php
// start at the beginning of your output.
ob_start();



        /*
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
output will be here, whatever it is.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

```
// and after your output.

ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

HOpe this one helps ..:)